# Detect if a row read in by fgetcsv is the last row of the csv file with PHP 7.4

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

Is it possible to detect in the following code example if the current row is the last row? Here is my code:

```
$file = \fopen('/path/to/file.csv', 'rb');
while (($row = \fgetcsv($file, 0, ';')) !== false) {
    // Detect if it is the last row
    $isLastRow = ?;

    // Do some stuff for all rows and pass if it is the last row
    $myService->handleRow($row, $isLastRow);
}
```

I already tried it with `$isLastRow = feof($file);`, but that was not working. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What you need to achieve? What about moving `$myService` outside `while` loop if should be processed after loop is done?

Comment: @pavel, the want it the other way round *and pass if it is the last row*

Comment: You can't tell which row is the last row _inside the loop_ unless you know ahead of time how many rows there will be.

Comment: I want to import a huge product csv file to a shop and thus I dont want to load the whole file to RAM. So I have to work off row by row but I need to know when the last row is reached.

Comment: What's so special about the last row that it needs to be processed differently?

Comment: @AlexHowansky "MyService" is processing the data and then it does not directly import the data to database, but it stores the prepared data to an array. And once the array contains e.g. 100 entries OR if it is the last row, "MyService" should store the entries of the array to database.

Comment: Could you change `$myService->handleRow` to flush the data out when you pass null as the `$row` value.

Comment: Then just explicitly call `$myservice->store()` (or `flush()` or whatever it's called) after the loop exits to save anything left over from the last iteration. (Or better, do it in a destructor so that the caller doesn't have to worry about it.)

Comment: Ok, I will try your approaches, thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just re-arrange the code a little?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution after all, contrary to the comments. This seems to work:

```
$fileEndPosition = \filesize('/path/to/file.csv');
$file = \fopen('/path/to/file.csv', 'rb');
while (($row = \fgetcsv($file, 0, ';')) !== false) {
    // Detect current file pointer position
    $currentPosition = ftell($file); 

    // Detect if it is the last row
    $isLastRow = $currentPosition >= $fileEndPosition;

    // Do some stuff for all rows and pass if it is the last row
    $myService->handleRow($row, $isLastRow);
}
```